# Would it be appropriate to consider applying to a new graduate program as a five-year/dual degree program student?

Tags: degree

I am not sure if students who have deferred from graduate programs tell the school that they no longer can or will be attending?

I've been accepted into a BA/MA program where I am talking credits which will be counted towards the second half of the program. Since I am still a considered as a resident of my undergraduate institution, we are considered students who have "deferred."

I just learned about a Ph.D. program that would provide full funding for students as well as a stipend for housing (of course, this is only for the first year--funding will decrease over the years, but I think this may give me a chance to get a job to pay off the costs). These are two issues that I have been considering for the second year of the  dual degree program. I am pretty much secure in the first year because I am still receiving funding as an undergraduate student; however, in the second year I will be subject to tuition, housing costs, etc like a graduate student. I have accepted that. However, after learning about the Ph.D. program, I want to consider applying. Is it possible or worth it?

Comment: Who is going to stop you? If it makes financial sense then then answer is obviously yes, it is worth it.